# Show tray icon - where to get resource from?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, notifyicon

I'm not very familar with WinAPI programming, so that's more or les a beginners question.

I'm currently porting a plain console-application to Windows. It does use only some socket functions and don't has any GUI, so this is an easy thing. To hide the ugly, black console I'm using

```
int APIENTRY WinMain()
```

and don't open any windows. Now I have to show a tray icon to just to notify user this application is running. I also found some nice example code demonstrating how to use Shell_NotifyIcon(). Where I'm failing at is loading of related icon:

```
niData.hIcon=
   (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
   MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_AAAA),
   IMAGE_ICON,
   GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
   GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
   LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

I already have a .ico file containing severals icons in different sizes and a .rc file where IDI_AAAA points to this icon:

```
IDI_AAAA               ICON                    "my_icon.ico"
```

.rc file is added to my project but the compiler - of course - complains it does not know IDI_AAAA. So...how do I have to make the connection from IDI_AAAA in .rc file to a valid definition in .cpp file making it possible for LoadImage() to get the icon?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to link the compiled resource file to the executable.

Comment: David Heffernan: it fails earlier, the compiler complains about "error C2065: 'IDI_AAAA' : undeclared identifier" which is clear since IDI_AAAA currently exists in .rc file only

Comment: Well, that error could not be any clearer. You understand what "undeclared identifier" means right? Normally you'd put that declaration in a resources header file and include it in the .rc file and the source file.